# How to count the number of matches captured by the regex in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem counting the number of matches captured by the regex because it doesn't have a count function.

Here is my code:

```
 var pathRegex = new Regex(".+?\\:\\/\\/.+? (\\/.+?)(?:#|\\?|$)");
 var result = pathRegex.Match(url);
            if (!(result.Success))
            {
                pathRegex = new Regex("/\\/.*/");
                result = pathRegex.Match(url);

                if (result.Success && result.Length == 1)
                {
                    return result.Value;
                }else
                {
                    return "";
                } 
            }
```

I've tried `result.Length` but it only counts the length of the string that has a match. Do you have any suggestions or workaround on this?

Comment: What are you actually doing? URL verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MatchCollection matches = pathRegex.Matches(url);
var count = matches.Count;
```

[Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Match` only returns the first occurrence as a single Match object. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8). 
Therefore, it `Count` is not available and `if (result.Success)` is sufficient for your case.

If you want multiple matches you need [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8) which returns a MatchCollection.